android compose text field wrong keyboard opens when app opens from background
hey so i have a very weird problem with Jetpack Compose TextField. i have this component here:
@Composable
fun AppTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: String,
    label: String,
    singleLine: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    colors: TextFieldColors? = null,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    supportingText: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit
){
    OutlinedTextField(value = value, onValueChange = {
        onValueChanged(it)
    },
        label = {
            Text(text = label)
        },
        singleLine = singleLine,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = colors ?: OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary,
            unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary,
            disabledBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary,
            disabledTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
            disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = keyboardType),
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
        isError = isError,
        supportingText = supportingText,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        enabled = enabled,
        leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
        minLines = minLines
        )
}

and i call this component throughout my whole application. it helps me with keeping the same style everywhere and even more modularizing the app components. now the problem is that i have to have the TextField KeyboardType in one of my screens as a numeric keyboard.
so when i open the screen and focus the keyboard for the first time, everything looks good and the numeric keyboard opens up as it should. but whenever i open any other app or just put the app on the background and open it again and focus on the TextField keyboard goes to text keyboard instead of number and even worst, even if i click the numbers on the text keyboard, nothing gets added to the value of my textfield.
i searched everywhere, i tried every single method but none of them worked for me.
anyone has this problem?
im using galaxy a24 with android 14 and using compose material3 version 1.2.1

so the bug was inside of the jetpack compose material 3 itself version 1.2.1, i upgraded it to version 1.3.0 and everything is working smoothly
